# Regex not matching the end of a filename

Tags: java, regex

I need to filter out the files in a directory that end with "_done". 

The directory contains three .txt files, namely *format1.txt*, *format2.txt* and *format2_done.txt* that needs to be filtered out.

The following sample correctly lists all the files:

```
System.out.println("all files: ");
String[] files = folder.list();
for (String item : files) {
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

Output:

```
all files: 
format1.txt
format2.txt
format2_done.txt
```

But the following sample:

```
System.out.println("filtered: ");
String[] filteredFiles = folder.list((File folder, String name) 
                         -> {return !(name.matches("_done.txt>"));});

for (String item : filteredFiles) {
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

produces the same output and doesn't filter anything:

```
filtered: 
format1.txt
format2.txt
format2_done.txt
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this regex instead [`.*_done\\.txt$`](https://regex101.com/r/iFFK3D/1) like this :

```
String[] filteredFiles = folder.list((File folder, String name)
        -> !name.matches(".*_done\\.txt$")
);
```

details :

- `.*` zero or more character
- followed by `_done\\.txt`, note that you should to escape the dot with `\\`
- `$` end anchor

Or you can just use [String::endsWith](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith-java.lang.String-) :

```
String[] filteredFiles = folder.list((File folder, String name)
        -> !name.endsWith("_done.txt")
);
```

Comment: It worked! Of course, *endsWith* method is pretty straightforward but I am trying to incorporate more regex in my code.